# php how to display variable anywhere on the page

Tags: php

my code if to show error when option is not selected from select box

here's my variable

```
$schanName = 'Please select an Option';
```

here's my code

```
if($_POST['thisfolder'] == 'default') { 
echo $schanName;
return; 
}
```

now my point is how do i display this message `Please select a Option` any where on the page ?

because i have 2 echo one there on my if statement and second if i put inside div like this

```
<div ><?php echo $schanName; ?></div>
```

this is not gonna work it shows the error at the bottom of my page

Edit #2

not sure if you guys reading my question.

on my page i have a form with select box

and i have this at bottom of it

Here is div to show error

```
<div ><?php echo $schanName; ?></div>
```

`HERE is Form`

```
<?php

$schanName = 'Please select a Channel';
if($_POST['thisfolder'] == 'default') { 
echo $schanName;
return; 
}

?>
```

it is just like this on my page. and i am sure i don't have problem with my div placement

Edit #3 Whole page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="error"> i must display that error here</div>

<form class="s_submit" method="post"> 
<input class="t_box" type='text' name='filename' placeholder='File name'>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button> 
</form> 

<?php
$fNum = 'File name is Required';
if(empty($_POST['filename'])) {
echo $fNum;
return; 
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: store it using session

Comment: how bro i am new in php. just started learning

Comment: You can echo it in whatever part of the HTML code you want it to appear in.

Comment: can you show me your code as well place where you want to echo error message?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: While you said the error message appear at the bottom of your page, I guess the issue with <div> placement....try to adjust your <div> location..or post more code and info.

Comment: @PramodKharade check my question now please

Comment: @Mm Pp , Please post all html along with php code and place where you want to echo message?

Comment: @PramodKharade check my question now i have added the whole page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
       <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
           <title>Untitled Document</title>
       </head>

       <body>
           <div id="error"> 
               <?php
                  // not asked so it does not show an error when no form was submitted
                  if(isset($_POST['filename']) && empty($_POST['filename'])) {
                       echo 'File name is Required';
                   }
                ?>
           </div>

          <form class="s_submit" method="post"> 
              <input class="t_box" type='text' name='filename' placeholder='File name'>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button> 
          </form> 



       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what if i put the whole my php code at bottom and div at top how do i point it or how do i tell that div to show that error instead of putting the whole code inside div error ?

Comment: there are 1000 of examples ... maybe here :https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete

Comment: because i have a variable for what to say for error

Comment: thats not possible .. because its not defined before

Comment: you can do something like this if you dont wanna have to much php in your html code
https://gist.github.com/boscho87/c7691c2910bad0e23ed06a98cb59aed1

Comment: i see here it is possible don't know why you said not posside https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete what i meant is to set a variable like there it's on that link for email field

Comment: this one `$emailErr `

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this? please you should post more code and tell us want you want exatly :)

```
   //thisfolder is empty or not set
if(empty($_POST['thisfolder']) { 
    echo $schanName;
   }else {
    //thisfolder is not empty
    echo $_POST['thisfolder'];
 }
```

Comment: check my question now please

Comment: bro. it's so simple. i have a variable with name of `$schanName` and at the bottom of that i have my code

Comment: my question is how do i echo out this $schanName any where i want on the page

Comment: you see right now echo is here `if($_POST['thisfolder'] == 'default') { 
echo $schanName;
return; ` but i don't it like this i want to echo it out some where else

Comment: here i want it like this `<div ><?php echo $schanName; ?></div>`

Comment: post your file with all html and all php .... if you really wanna learn php .... start with a good youtoube tutorial

Comment: so is there an error message or something from php?

Comment: because if i do my php code like this `$schanName = 'Please select a Channel';
if($_POST['thisfolder'] == 'default') { 

return; 
}` without putting echo here and put echo inside that div it doesn't work

Comment: do you send a form with mehtod post ?

Comment: remove the return statement.

Comment: yes it is if statement if select box not selected then it shows message that is on my variable here $schanName = 'Please select a Channel';

Comment: did you try `empty($_POST['thisfolder'])` instead of `$_POST['thisfolder']  == 'default` ?

Comment: check my question now i have added the whole page